# Set scrollbar on specific position for selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a requirement to set the position of `scrollbar` on specific position in a select box.

Somewhere I got that I can use `scrollTop()` but it's not working in select box.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Some code will be helpful.

Comment: @SrinivasPai it's just a simple select box nothing else. so you can take any example of select box.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do that, but you can always trick it into looking like that by placing a div around the select, and setting the width/height and scroll on that. [Taken from here](http://bytes.com/topic/html-css/answers/512276-horizontal-scroll-bars-select-box).

Answer (score 0):

There are only one way to move top of is select 1 st index option on click event.